# 2016 Honda CRV - Radio Buttons Falling Off

Tags: honda, audio, crv

I've had my CRV for about six years now, and in the last six months or so, have had multiple radio buttons on the left hand side start falling off (picture below) without explanation.

While I can "push" the buttons back in, they pop back out extremely easily, just through normal usage like a single push. Unfortunately, I've already lost the "Menu" key because of this, although I still have the Brightness and Eject keys. It's still possible to click the buttons if I use something like a pen to jab at the smaller button, but this is far from ideal.

Oddly enough, a relative has the identical vehicle as me, almost the same age, and their buttons are still tight and show no sign of moving.

I've talked to Honda about it, but their only suggestion is to replace the entire stereo which is A) extreme overkill; B) obscenely expensive.

I've also looked into getting an after market stereo but that's still far from cheap, even though it's cheaper than replacing the original stereo from Honda, and I might lose some of my current functionality.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to replace the buttons and make them "tight" again, I would appreciate it. Or something I could use as a replacement button since I've lost the Menu button anyway.

I've considered something like crazy glue, but I'm not sure how I could do it without potentially destroying the click mechanism.

Thanks!

[image: Missing Buttons on 2016 CRV Radio]

Comment: Suggestion 1)  Get a busted/old/used radio from junkyard.  Check local, and check ebay.   2) Put a piece of clear tape across the whole button array.  That should at least keep them in place.  3)  Don't push so hard.  Why are yours popping off but nobody elses is?  Do you have gorilla thumbs?   Not an insult, just an observation.   Some people are gentle with stuff, some people wanna see if they can push the buttons through the back of the unit.

Comment: Heh, I'm 5 foot nothing and have no measurable upper body strength - definitely not an issue :). I could see the menu key loosening from heavy usage, but the other two keys are barely ever used so even that's weird. The back key is used a lot and it's still fine. The tape idea might work, I'm not sure what tapes would still well to the plastic though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reddit subs which are configured for people to request 3D printed models [to be designed/constructed](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Drequests) and [to be printed](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprintmything/). Often enough, the model designer can print the object.

If you can release the buttons and provide close-up detailed images along with precise measurements, you may be able to get a 3D printed replacement for far less than your current options.

Making judgements on modifications to the existing buttons with the intent of improving the "grip" may provide for a longer lasting replacement.

Expect an exchange of test parts and iteration of the model in order to get a working fit and to get a reliable fit.

Comment: There is a 3D print shop close to where I live. Unfortunately all the buttons are different sizes, so I would still have no reference for the menu key, although the others might be okay.

Answer (score 0):

After even more buttons fell off than the original photo, I eventually took the advice of buying a refurbished model and replaced the whole thing.

There was no other reasonable solution I could come up with (short of an after market model, but I was disappointed with that option).

Anyway the buttons are all present and working on the refurb, fingers crossed the first one was more of a fluke and they stay stable...

[image]